# Go: How can I "unpack" a struct?

Tags: reflection, go

I have a struct:

```
type mystruct struct {
    Foo string
    Bar int
}
```

I'd like to create SQL insert statements from the struct which have the following form:

```
m := mystruct{ "Hello" , 1 }
query := "INSERT INTO mytbl ( foo, bar ) VALUES ( ?,? )"
res,err := db.Exec(query, m.Foo, m.Bar)
```

Now my question is: how can I make the last line dynamically from the struct (or m) itself? I am able to get the struct names using `reflect`, but I don't know how to create the `[]interface{}` slice for the `db.Exec()` call. This is what I have tried: (http://play.golang.org/p/GR1Bb61NFH)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type mystruct struct {
    Foo string
    Bar int
}

func main() {
    m := mystruct{"Foo", 1}
    fmt.Println(readNames(m))
    x := unpackStruct(m)
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", x)
}

func unpackStruct(a interface{}) []interface{} {

    // "convert" a to m t

    // doesn't work, from 'laws of reflection'
    s := reflect.ValueOf(&t).Elem()
    typeOfT := s.Type()
    for i := 0; i < s.NumField(); i++ {
        f := s.Field(i)
        fmt.Printf("%d: %s %s = %v\n", i,
            typeOfT.Field(i).Name, f.Type(), f.Interface())
    }

    // this is in principle what I want:
    m := mystruct{"Hello", 2}
    var ret []interface{}
    ret = make([]interface{}, s.NumField())
    ret[0] = m.Foo
    ret[1] = m.Bar
    return ret
}

// works fine:
func readNames(a interface{}) []string {
    s := reflect.TypeOf(a)
    lenStruct := s.NumField()
    ret := make([]string, lenStruct)

    for i := 0; i < lenStruct; i++ {
        ret[i] = s.Field(i).Name
    }
    return ret
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand what your misunderstanding was so I won't post a full response for now, but the error mainly lies in `s := reflect.ValueOf(&t).Elem()`. The line is needlessly complex and I'm not sure what it's doing, s := reflect.ValueOf(a) works fine. http://play.golang.org/p/C9cv6uw97k

Comment: @Jsor that's exactly what I want. Somehow I was unable to get my thinking in the right direction. If you post this as an answer, I'll be happy to "accept" it.

Comment: If the argument, `a`, is meant to be an interface which can hold any struct, then you can actually pass `a` directly to ValueOf, since ValueOf takes an interface as an argument: `s := reflect.ValueOf(a)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If getting the values of the fields is your issue, this code snippet should help:

```
s := reflect.ValueOf(a)
ret := make([]interface{}, s.NumField())
for i := 0; i < s.NumField(); i++ {
    ret[i] = s.Field(i).Interface()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If creating the `[]interface{}` value is your problem, using `reflect`'s slice creation mechanisms should work nicely:

```
slc := reflect.MakeSlice(InterfaceType, len, cap) // See the link below for creating InterfaceType
slc.Index(0).Set(TargetValue)
return slc.Interface()
```

(Here's the above-mentioned [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/qgJy_H2GysY)).

Modifying the above code to loop over the values in the struct instead of just the 0th index shouldn't be too bad.

Comment: I am able to make the interface (`ret = make([]interface{}, s.NumField())` in my code). Or are we talking about different things? My problem is how to get the values of the struct.

Comment: Yeah, I just find that doing it this way is easier and more reliable. But if that's your issue (I misunderstood your original question) I'll repost.